# Code checking the result of std::unordered_set::find won't compile

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, unordered-set

I am writing a program to determine whether all characters in a string are unique or not. I am trying to do this using an unordered_set. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool uniqueChars(string word) {

    unordered_set<char> set;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        auto character = set.find(word[i]);

        // if word[i] is found in set then not all chars are unique
        if (character == word[i]) {
            return false;
        }
        //else add word[i] to set
        else {
            set.insert(word[i]);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {

    string word;
    getline(cin, word);

    bool result = uniqueChars(word);
    return 0;
}
```

It is giving me this error:

> |15|error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::__detail::_Node_iterator' and 'char')|

I believe that means that character is not comparable to word[i], but I'm not sure.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [std::unordered_set::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) returns an iterator, not the element. It can't be compared to the element directly.

You could check whether the element was found or not by comparing the iterator with [std::unordered_set::end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/end). e.g.

```
auto character = set.find(word[i]);

// if word[i] is found in set then not all chars are unique
if (character != set.end()) {
    return false;
}
//else add word[i] to set
else {
    set.insert(word[i]);
}
```

BTW: Better not to use `set` as the name of variable, which is the name of another STL container.

Comment: Thanks! It works but what does set.end() do? Does it iterate through the set?

Comment: @CheetahBongos No, [it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/end) just returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the container, and then could be used as a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the return value of [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert). It tells you whether a duplicate was found during insertion (in which case nothing is inserted).

```
bool uniqueChars(string word) {
    unordered_set<char> set;
    for ( char c : word ) {
        if ( ! set.insert( c ).second ) {
            return false; // set didn't insert c because of a duplicate.
        }
    }
    return true; // No duplicates.
}
```

However, this isn't as efficient as it might look. `unordered_set` is a heap-based hash table and its implementation is fairly heavyweight. A lightweight bit-vector works well for classifying characters.

```
#include <bitset>

constexpr int char_values = numeric_limits< char >::max()
                          - numeric_limits< char >::min() + 1;

bool uniqueChars(string word) {
    bitset< char_values > set;

    for ( char c : word ) {
        int value_index = c - numeric_limits< char >::min();

        if ( set[ value_index ] ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            set[ value_index ] = true;
        }
    }
    return true; // No duplicates.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*character == word[i]
```

> ( This is the way to access the characters but it is not needed and it
>   should be guided by a check whether it points to the past to  the last
>   element)

The *charcater is basically referencing the already inserted charcater.

```
  if(character != set1.end() )
     return false; // as we are sure  that it is not unique character string
```

You have to dereference it. but in that case you also need to do the whether it return iterator pointing to `set::end``.

By the way there is a really a simple way to do what you are trying to do.

```
bool uniqueChars(string word) {

    unordered_set<char> set1;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) 
        auto character = set1.insert(word[i]);

    return set1.size()==word.length();
}
```

**"set" is a key word in c++**

Comment: set::end Returns an iterator referring to the past-the-end element in the set container.

The past-the-end element is the theoretical element that would follow the last element in the set container. It does not point to any element, and thus shall not be dereferenced.

Comment: Take a closer look at `uniqueChars`. Perhaps `find` should be `insert`? Also, you copypasta'd in the comment that it "shall not be dereferenced," but you dereferenced it in the answer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter.: Thanks..modified. I just overlooked it.

Comment: @Potatoswatter.: I have modified please check it once.

Comment: Simply put, the answer should not contain the text `*character`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter.: I just showed him a way to access the character ..i am not encouraging it. And also mentioned checks to be performed to do so.

Comment: @The algorithm he describes never needs to access the characters in the set, so why is that helpful?

Comment: @Potatoswatter.: it's not needed here but it doesn't killl if he knows. I just showed him something that might help him later too.